# groupadd command not working error: 'is not a valid group name'

Tags: 20.04, bash, useradd

I re-did the code to something less complicated and now it says:

ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ ./newuseradd.sh Newbies.csv
[sudo] password for ubuntu:
useradd: group 'acct' does not exist
useradd: group 'hr' does not exist
useradd: group 'purch' does not exist

Script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   echo "USAGE: $0 FILE"
    exit 7
 fi

 sed -i'.bak' 's/Accounting/acct/;s/Purchasing/purch/;s/Human Resources/hr/;s/Information Technology/it/' $1 # Part 3 - transforming the group names


 while read line; do
    userinfo=($(echo $line | tr ',' ' '))
    firstinitial=$(echo "${userinfo[1]}" | cut -c1)
    username=$(echo ${firstinitial}${userinfo[0]} | tr A-Z a-z)
    echo useradd $username -g ${userinfo[2]} -G employee -c ${userinfo[3]}  -m #Part 2
    echo "$(date): $username, ${userinfo[1]}, ${userinfo[0]}, $?" >> it-log.txt #Part 4 assigment- it log

    echo -n "${userinfo[0]}, ${userinfo[1]}" >> hr-log.txt
    grep "$username" /etc/passwd | cut -d':' -f1,7,3 | tr ':' ',' >> hr-log.txt
done < $1 #part 1 assigment
```

[Assigment with the details](https://learn-us-east-1-prod-fleet01-xythos.content.blackboardcdn.com/blackboard.learn.xythos.prod/584b1d8497c84/121754011?X-Blackboard-Expiration=1636005600000&X-Blackboard-Signature=SFU55emHD%2BKyFasw7mbgGBkmVYVCyJo4m%2BBi0VYIxsQ%3D&X-Blackboard-Client-Id=100004&response-cache-control=private%2C%20max-age%3D21600&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27Assignment%25204.pdf&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211104T000000Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=21600&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAYDKQORRYTKBSBE4S%2F20211104%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=57e4d194670edb15e1aa0199fe756227e721120fa063f02dbd41355119f9004b)

Comment: I think that `groupadd` only takes one groupname argument at the time.

Comment: Thank you, is there an easier way for me to do this then? I have been watching a lot of videos and doing some reading online, and this is how my script might seem a little frankstein-ish...

Comment: @Steeldriver unquoted `${a[*]}` will not expand to comma-separated (neighter will `${a[@]}` in any form), but `"${a[*]}"` will, so it will loop: `IFS=,; a=(a b c); echo ${a[*]} "${a[*]}"`

Comment: @AnneBright OK apparently I'm wrong - please ignore my previous comment

Comment: @AnneBrigh: @Steeldriver is still right though because you changed IFS to `,`, `${groups[*]}` won't split as expected (`" \n\t"`), think you can comment `IFS` as it's not used I believe. (secgroup= is assigned as a variable but addressed as an array)

Comment: there are a lot of other problems, you should probably echo the different "$variables" to be sure the parsing works.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think it's best to serialize your data in a stride list (of 4).

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A passwd group
declare -la a=()
while IFS="," read -r b c d e; do
    a+=("$b" "$c" "$d" "$e"); a=("${a[@]// }")
done < newbies.csv

for i in passwd group; do
    while IFS=: read -r j _ ; do
        eval ${i}\[\$j\]=1; done < /etc/$i
done

lookup(){
    local a
    a=${1}[$2]; [[ ${!a} = 1 ]]
}

for ((y = 0, x = 0; y < ${#a[@]}; y += 4)); do
    read -r \
        lastname firstname department uid \
    <<< "${a[@]:$y:4}"
    printf Processing:\ %s\\n \
    "$lastname $firstname $department $uid"

    lookup group \
    "$department" || echo groupadd "$department"

    lookup passwd \
    "$firstname" || { \
    echo useradd -n -c "Assigment4" -g "$department" "$firstname" && ((x++)); }
done
echo "Complete. $x accounts have been created."
```